# Go Mongo Driver Retrieve Schemaless Documents

Tags: mongodb, go

While working with Mongo Go Driver I want to retrieve Schemaless Documents.

I am able to retrieve documents using `bson.M` `json:",inline" bson:",inline"`
But this adds extra **"M"** key in json when i try to Decode to a struct

```
type Product struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    ProductId string `bson:"product_id" json:"product_id"`
    bson.M `json:",inline" bson:",inline"`
}
```

Output:-

```
{
 "id":"<ObjectId>",
 "M":{
    "some":""
  }
}
```

But instead what i want how it is stored in Mongo.

```
{
  "id":"<ObjectId>",
  "some":""
}
```

I cant use directly something like this as I want to cast it to struct to work with some properties

```
var pr bson.M
err := p.FindOne(ctx, &p.options,query, &pr)
```

How can I remove that extra key which is getting added while converting schemaless Documents from Mongo?

Do I need to explicitly overwrite MarshalJSON() or is there something provided using Tags?

Comment: You'll need to implement `MarshalJSON`. `inline` is not one of the supported struct tags for `encoding/json`: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

Comment: @Adrian I was confirming if there is something which I am missing. Lastly i thought to implement customJsonMarshal . BTW why -1?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I remove that extra key which is getting added while converting schemaless Documents from Mongo?

You can just define a field mapping name, which will be flattened when marshalled. For example:

```golang
type Product struct {
    ID          primitive.ObjectID      `bson:"_id"`
    ProductId   string                  `bson:"product_id"`
    Others      bson.M                  `bson:",inline"`
}
```

When you decode a document, you'll see that it will include other fields without the `Others` name. For example if you have a document:

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("5e8d330de85566f5a0557ea4"), 
 "product_id": "foo", 
 "some": "x", 
 "more": "y"
}
```

```golang
doc := Product{}
err = cur.Decode(&doc)
fmt.Println(doc)
// Outputs 
// {ObjectID("5e8d330de85566f5a0557ea4") foo map[more:y some:x]}
```

> I cant use directly something like this as I want to cast it to struct to work with some properties

You can use this directly for a query predicate. For example:

```golang
// After decoding 'doc' to product
var result bson.M
err := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), doc).Decode(&result)
```

Tested using [MongoDB Go driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) v1.3.2

**UPDATED:**

If you would like to return JSON, you could use [bson.MarshalExtJSON()](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson?tab=doc#MarshalExtJSON). This should be easier as well in terms of dealing with objects that don't exist in JSON. i.e. ObjectId. For example:

```golang
// After decoding 'doc' to product
ejson, err := bson.MarshalExtJSON(doc, true, false)
fmt.Println(string(ejson))
```

Comment: The output wld be ```{"_id": ObjectId("5e8d330de85566f5a0557ea4"), 
 "product_id": "foo","Others":{"some": "x", "more": "y"}}```. But I want as is structure in mongo. I Dont want keys inside ```"Others"``` as this is not what is stored in Mongo.

Comment: Output from what command ? The output above is an output from a code snippet. It would be good if you put an example code. Also note that you can just use it directly to pass into FindOne.

Comment: @Art, updated the answer related to your question about marshalling to JSON